# auto generate table and grouped values by name and get multiple values

Tags: mysql

hey everyone I a have question for you

I am working on store management system and I want to select all the data from the store table and display it in a html table format  so far I have tried to display it using the code below

Name............Store...............Quantity..............unit

Door........... store1..............970...................pcs......       Decide

Desk........... store2..............10000..............pcs......          Decide

Door........... store1..............50.....................pcs......          Decide

```html
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable responsive">
    <thead>
    <tr> 
  
          <th>Item</th>
    
    <th>name</th>
    
    <th>location</th>
        
    <th>Quantity</th>
    
    <th>Unit</th>
    
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  
      <?php
      if (isset($_POST['search'])){
      
      foreach ($_POST['name'] as $attrib) { 
      
                        $query = mysql_query("select * from store where name= '".$attrib."'") or die(mysql_error());
      
      $num_row = mysql_num_rows($query);
      
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                            $id = $row['id'];
       
                            ?>
        
                            <tr class="del<?php echo $id ?>">
        
                                <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        
                                <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
        
        <td><?php echo $row['location']; ?></td>
        
        <td><?php echo $row['quantity']; ?></td>
        
        <td><?php echo $row['unit']; ?></td>
        
       <td> 
                        <a href="inventorysearch.php<?php echo '?id='.$id; ?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Decide</a></li>
                       </td>
```

but what I need to display is select only grouped name for those repeated names from the database and display it like the one below.

Name............Store1..............Store2..............Store3

Door........... 970 ....................50.......................0........Decide

Desk........... 10......................10000.................0........Decide

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate results using GROUP BY, and optionally perform arithmetic on all items in a group (e.g. SUM)

Documentation:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html

However this does not let you easily convert rows into columns, you could potentially use GROUP_CONCAT to munge all the values into a single column, but it is ugly and prone to issues with parsing special character, etc.

The best case would be to perform this work in your PHP.  My suggestion would be to:

(1) First generate a list of stores, e.g.

SELECT DISTINCT location FROM store WHERE name=x

(2) Use this information to create an array of locations, and print your table header

(3) When you run your actual query, order the results by location first, then any other parameters.  This means you will fetch all locations sequentially for each given item.

SELECT * FROM store WHERE name=x ORDER BY location

(4) Iterate over each row until the location changes, now you have a number of rows for the same location, you can then create a combined row output by iterating over them and ensuring each location is output in the correct column

To ensure the list of locations does not change between the two queries, i recommend ensuring tx_isolation is REPEATABLE READ and then use BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT around the two selects to ensure they read from the same data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to transpose column values as row

`Step 1 .` select all record from database

`Step 2 .` group record by Store

your data array look like

```
$array =Array (0 => Array
                    (
                        'id' => 1,
                        'name' => 'Door',
                        'location' => 'store1',
                        'quantity' =>970,
                        'unit' =>'pcs'
                    ),
                1 => Array
                    (
                        'id' => 2,
                        'name' => 'Desk',
                        'location' => 'store2',
                        'quantity' =>1000,
                        'unit' =>'pcs'
                    ),
                2 => Array
                    (
                        'id' => 3,
                        'name' => 'Door',
                        'location' => 'store1',
                        'quantity' =>50,
                        'unit' =>'pcs'
                    ),
                3 => Array
                    (   
                        'id' => 4,
                        'name' => 'Desk',
                        'location' => 'store2',
                        'quantity' =>970,
                        'unit' =>'pcs'
                    ),
                4 => Array
                (   
                    'id' => 5,
                    'name' => 'Desk',
                    'location' => 'store2',
                    'quantity' =>70,
                    'unit' =>'pcs'
                ),
                5 => Array
                (
                    'id' => 6,
                    'name' => 'Door',
                    'location' => 'store1',
                    'quantity' =>150,
                    'unit' =>'pcs'
                ),
                6 => Array
                    (
                        'id' => 7,
                        'name' => 'Door',
                        'location' => 'store2',
                        'quantity' =>120,
                        'unit' =>'pcs'
                    ),
                7 => Array
                    (
                        'id' => 8,
                        'name' => 'Desk',
                        'location' => 'store1',
                        'quantity' =>230,
                        'unit' =>'pcs'
                    ),
                8 => Array
                    (
                        'id' => 9,
                        'name' => 'Desk',
                        'location' => 'store1',
                        'quantity' =>50,
                        'unit' =>'pcs'
                    ),
                9 => Array
                    (   
                        'id' => 10,
                        'name' => 'Desk',
                        'location' => 'store3',
                        'quantity' =>970,
                        'unit' =>'pcs'
                    ),
                10=> Array
                (   
                    'id' => 11,
                    'name' => 'Desk',
                    'location' => 'store3',
                    'quantity' =>70,
                    'unit' =>'pcs'
                ),
                11 => Array
                (
                    'id' => 12,
                    'name' => 'pankaj',
                    'location' => 'store1',
                    'quantity' =>150,
                    'unit' =>'pcs'
                ),
            );
```

And desired result array look like after grouping column value

```
$resultArray =array();
            foreach($array as $key =>$value){
                 $itemKey =$value['location'];
                 @$resultArray[$value['name']][$itemKey] +=$value['quantity'];
            }
```

final array

```
Array
(
    [Door] => Array
        (
            [store1] => 1170
            [store2] => 120
        )

    [Desk] => Array
        (
            [store2] => 2040
            [store1] => 280
            [store3] => 1040
        )

    [pankaj] => Array
        (
            [store1] => 150
        )

)
```

Now Iterate resultArray key will be header of table and value will be row of table